# how to find the maximum difference between two columns' value in a row of a data from

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame like this:

```
row     name   val1   val2   val3  val4  val5 
  0    sf_park   12     14    23     22    45 
  1    ny_park   21     40    36     38    39 
  2    dc_park   34     30    30     46    11 
  3    tx_park   20     22    22     29    91
```

and I want to add a new column to my data which shows the maximum of difference between values. For example, in row.1 the max difference is between `val1` and `val2`=19 however in row.0 the max difference is between `val1` and `val5`=33.
i tried to add a column `max` and `min` and thier difference in another one.but I had problems with `max()` function in order of using it for a values of a row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [**`np.ptp`**](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.ptp.html) across the first axis:

```
df['new'] = np.ptp(df.iloc[:, 2:].values, 1)

   row     name  val1  val2  val3  val4  val5  new
0    0  sf_park    12    14    23    22    45   33
1    1  ny_park    21    40    36    38    39   19
2    2  dc_park    34    30    30    46    11   35
3    3  tx_park    20    22    22    29    91   71
```